# Problema em mostrar SMS recebido

Tags: vb.net, sms

Fala galera!

Estou tentando mostrar um **SMS** recebido numa caixa de texto em um **Form** que eu tenho, mas em vez de me mostrar a mensagem que recebo no meu SIM, mostra algo como **+CMTI: "ME",33**. Vou deixar o código que tenho em baixo:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
Dim inputData As String = ""
Public Event DataReceived As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
    SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 0
    SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
    SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
    SerialPort1.RtsEnable = True

    SerialPort1.Open()
End Sub



Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    inputData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
    Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoUpdate))
End Sub

Public Sub DoUpdate()
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & inputData
End Sub


End Class
```

Será que alguém me pode dar uma ajuda de como mostrar a mensagem no chamado ***plain text*** e não como está mostrando?

**NOTA: Tanto a PortName, como o resto encontra-se correto**

Comment: O que vc tem em `inputData` na linha `inputData = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()`?

Comment: O ReadExisting recebe a ultima mensagem que chegou, no meu caso, quando eu envio um SMS o ReadExisting vai armazenar essa mensagem

Comment: Sim, e o que ele retorna e armazena em `inputData`?

Comment: Qual API você está usando para encaminhar/receber essas mensagens ?

Answer (score 1):

**+CMTI: "ME",33** é a indicação do módulo GSM que uma mensagem foi recebida, você precisar dar um comando para ler a mensagem. Os comandos podem variar um pouco de acordo com o módulo, mas costumam ser muito parecidos.

Você deve:

1. Você deve aguardar o recebimento de um: **+CMTI: mem,index** (mem->local de armazenamento da mensagem, index-> posição da mensagem na memória);
2. Dar o comando de leitura da SMS: **AT+CMGR=index[,mode]** (index-> posição da mensagem na memória, mode-> modo de leitura, 0 para normal);
3. Interpretar a mensagem recebida, ela virá, +ou-, nesse padrão: **+CMGR: "REC READ","+85291234567",,"07/02/18,00:12:05+32"**

**Hello, welcome to our SMS tutorial.**

**OK**

Aqui tem o datasheet de um módulo GSM bem comum, que pode ser parecido com o seu:http://www.espruino.com/datasheets/SIM900_AT.pdf